# Time synchronization with Daytime Protocol

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, time

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 and for some testing purposes I need to sync the system time with the NIST Internet Time Servers using the Daytime Protocol. The sync needs to occur 3-4 times a day, and the Windows Task Scheduler would be the preferred option.

Is there a reliable way to sync the system time using the Daytime Protocol?

Comment: Daytime Protocol is a service that one computer provides to others. Do you mean perhaps syncing with some Internet time server?

Comment: My goal is to sync with one of the NIST time servers using the Daytime protocol.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Internet Time Update interval see this detailed article :
[How to change Internet Time Update interval in Windows 10/8/7](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-internet-time-update-interval-windows).

The easiest way is to use regedit and navigate to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient`.

You need to change value of `SpecialPollInterval` to the number of seconds between
time requests, according to your needs.

You may also change the time server, either through the Windows time interface,
or in the registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters`
item `NtpServer`.
Fore more information see
[Configuring the Time Service: NtpServer and SpecialPollInterval](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/w32time/2008/02/26/configuring-the-time-service-ntpserver-and-specialpollinterval/).

Comment: The setup you described uses the Windows Time Service which follows the NTP specification and uses port 123 for time synchronization. I need to use the Daytime Protocol on port 13.

Comment: Port 13 implies a time-serving computer on the network. Where is this time server?

Comment: time.nist.gov and other nist.gov servers support the Daytime protocol on tcp port 13

Comment: But they support NTP as well. What's the purpose of using Daytime?

Comment: Might be for special needs, but I really think it was invented before ntp and is kept for historical reasons. [NIST Internet Time Servers](https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) says this :"of the NIST "DAYTIME" protocol on tcp port 13 are also strongly encouraged to upgrade to the network time protocol, which provides greater accuracy and requires less network bandwidth.". And not many servers support it.